# SE EE Netbeans compatibility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I'm learning Java and I've been reading these books: 
**Head First Java, Head First Servlets and JSP** to get started. 
Up until now, I've been doing most of the learning on HF Java on Eclipse IDE for Java developers(not the EE one). I also installed Java SE 7.
But now I want to move on to HF Servlets and JSP. The book says I need only Tomcat.
I also wanted to familiarize myself with NetBeans, so I downloaded Netbeans IDE for Java EE from this page https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html. 
My questions are :
 1.  Should I download Java EE before installing this version of Netbeans? Does this version include the Java EE or should I download it from Sun page? 
2. Is it overkill to install Netbeans for EE when all I need is Tomcat?

I **will** eventually learn EE I think... After these two books, I may read **HF Design Patterns or HF OOAnalysis & Design** Not sure if they're really necessary. 
 
3. What would be the appropriate learning order do you think is ? 

 Your answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**
Java EE is basically just Java SE with a few additional JARs for EE APIs like Servlets, JAX-WS etc. Installing multiple JREs on a computer will most likely lead to runtime issues because of the question which JRE is the default one, especially on Windows, since JAVA_HOME environment variable is not consulted in Windows Explorer, and tools like Ant and Maven depend on it.

For example, I keep several JREs/JDKs in one folder (unpacked, not installed) and list them in Eclipse to run applications I am developing on a particular JRE.

**2.**
When you, in Eclipse, do the following:

```
Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add...
```

and select Apache Tomcat 7, in the next step you can click on `Download and Install...` for Eclipse to download the latest Tomcat and set it up in selected folder as a target runtime that will run in the selected JRE.

You can also manually do the same and just point Eclipse to the folder where you installed / unpacked Tomcat.

When you then create the new Server for that Tomcat runtime you can assign a Dynamic Web Application project to it and it will be deployed on every change to the project. You can run it or debug it from inside Eclipse.

**3.**
Once you are on good terms with servlets and JSPs you should probably continue with the OO Analysis and Design, and then learn the Design Patterns. After those I recommend books on OSGi and [Java Application Architecture](http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-application-architecture).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Netbeans EE, it will also install other goodies such as Tomcat or Glassfish. This will allow you to debug your EE application directly from the IDE, as opposed to having everything dumped into Tomcat logs.

I think that since you are just beginning, doing everything from your IDE will allow you to better focus on what you need to learn.

If you learn the usual coding standards and recommended ways in Java SE, you shouldn't have any trouble in moving on to EE. If you read more about OOP and other design patterns, you will be better equipped to build decent applications and also better understand frameworks which are already available.